# Limit values to other ranges

Tags: google-sheets, data-validation

I'm trying to create a Sheets that defines various objects, and these objects sometimes reference each other (equivalent to SQL foreign key).

Is there a way that I can limit the values of a cell, to only those values that already exist in a range of another sheet?

So say I have a sheet of parents, and a sheet of kids. Each parent is a row in the sheet, and the first column is the name. In the kids sheet, the first column is a name, and the second column is mom. I want mom to be a dropdown of the names that exist in the parents sheet.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, with data validation:

[image: WA53034 example]

Eg Select ColumnB of Kids, Data (top right in image), Validation..., Cell range: Kids!B:B, Critera: List from a range Parents!A:A, select from options, Save.

This should fill the range with the grey down arrows and when clicking one of these a dropdown list such as that shown should appear.

If you were able to separate the mothers from the fathers (not divorce!) you should be able to apply a list of mothers only to one column and of fathers only to another, should you so wish.

Comment: Thanks this works. What if I have multiple ranges? (IE there's a person drop down, and I want it to be choosable from both kids and parents names)?

Comment: No, not something that complicated, just two lists you can choose from.